# How to use the reorder function to order columns of a bar graph by height

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df<-data.frame(State=as.factor(c("AL","MS","AL","NY","AL")),value=c(10,20,20,50,10))

  State value
1    AL    10
2    MS    20
3    AL    20
4    NY    50
5    AL    10

ggplot(df, aes(y=value, x=State)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

I'd like to reorder my bars by height from highest to shortest using the "reorder".  I found a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033342/reorder-a-factor-by-a-numeric-variable) but I didn't quite understand it and couldn't apply it to this problem.

Comment: You can try `DF$State=reorder(DF$State,-DF$value)` or you can include `descent=TRUE` if it is the case

Comment: You appear to have multiple values for state = 'AL', and currently you are "stacking" the bars for this one....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$State <- factor(df$State , 
                   levels=levels(df$State)[
                       order( tapply(df$value, df$State, sum), decreasing=TRUE)
                                         ])
```